# Why does Outlook 2010 break my HTML email body?

Tags: html, email, outlook, smtp, mime

Whenever I send a HTML email from my own server (with my own emailer code) to Outlook 2010, it strips out the first 2 characters of every single HTML attribute.

Here's a snippet from the HTML body (see the table attributes are screwed up):

```
<table cellpadding=" cellspacing=" border=" class=ostdata">  
<thead>                               
<tr>                                       
<th>Field</th>                                 
<th>Value</th>                               
</tr>     
</thead>
<tr>                
<th>Test</th>  
<td>Hello world!</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The full HTML body from Outlook 2010:

```
<style> BODY     {font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#4F4F4F;margin:8px;padding:0}      H1                           {font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:18px} .postdata                                                                                             {margin:10px;padding:10px 0} .postdata TABLE                                  {font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#4F4F4F}            .postdata TH                                                           {font-weight:bold;color:#FFF;text-align:left;padding:4px 8px;background-color:#555}                .postdata TD                                                      {padding:4px 8px}           .postdata THEAD TH        {font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;background-color:#444} .signature                                                                     {color:#9F9F9F;margin:40px 0 10px 0}</style>Test email with single <table style=olor: red" width=00%"><tr><td>Table data</td></tr></table><table cellpadding=" cellspacing=" border=" class=ostdata">  <thead>                               <tr>                                       <th>Field</th>                                 <th>Value</th>                               </tr>     </thead><tr>                <th>Test</th>  <td>Hello world!</td></tr></table>
```

The header from Outlook 2010 (I can't view the entire source in Outlook 2010):

```
Return-Path: <REMOVED>
Delivered-To: REMOVED
Received: (qmail 31757 invoked by alias); 22 Oct 2014 02:50:45 -0000
Delivered-To: alias-localdelivery-REMOVED
Received: (qmail 31751 invoked by uid 102); 22 Oct 2014 02:50:45 -0000
Date: 22 Oct 2014 02:50:45 -0000
Message-ID: <20141022025045.31750.REMOVED>
To: REMOVED
Subject:
From: REMOVED
X-Mailer: MailBot version 1.24
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
                boundary="MailBot=="
```

The full HTML email when opened with Mac Mail 7.3:

```
Return-Path: <REMOVED>
Delivered-To: REMOVED
Received: (qmail 32582 invoked by alias); 22 Oct 2014 02:57:39 -0000
Delivered-To: alias-localdelivery-REMOVED
Received: (qmail 32579 invoked by uid 102); 22 Oct 2014 02:57:39 -0000
Date: 22 Oct 2014 02:57:39 -0000
Message-ID: <20141022025739.32578.REMOVED>
To: REMOVED
Subject: 
From: REMOVED
X-Mailer: MailBot version 1.24
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="MailBot=="

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--MailBot==
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test email with single

--MailBot==
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<style> BODY    {font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#4F4F4F;margin:8px;padding:0}    H1      {font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin-top:18px} .postdata                     {margin:10px;padding:10px 0} .postdata TABLE            {font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#4F4F4F} .postdata TH                {font-weight:bold;color:#FFF;text-align:left;padding:4px 8px;background-color:#555} .postdata TD                {padding:4px 8px}   .postdata THEAD TH  {font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:uppercase;background-color:#444} .signature                 {color:#9F9F9F;margin:40px 0 10px 0}</style>Test email with single <table style="color: red" width="100%"><tr><td>Table data</td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" border="0" class="postdata">   <thead>     <tr>            <th>Field</th>          <th>Value</th>      </tr>   </thead><tr>    <th>Test</th>   <td>Hello world!</td></tr></table>

--MailBot==--
```

Why is Outlook doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms are consistent with declaring `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` but then not actually using this encoding, and the headers you posted seem to bear this out.

In QP, you would have `attribute=3D"value"` because the equals sign is a metacharacter in this encoding, and needs to be encoded as `=3D`. It is fathomable (though arguably not entirely correct) that a sequence of an equals sign followed by two non-hex (and non-newline) characters is discarded by Outlook as illegal.

In any event, I would blame your sending code -- which you are not showing --, not Outlook (even though I personally believe Outlook should be banned for other reasons).

Comment: I actually came up with this solution before reading your answer but you're completely right. I changed my encoding to `7bit` and it worked.

Comment: That's a perfect fix as long as you can guarantee that your data doesn't contain any overlong lines (the limit is somewhere around 1000 bytes IIRC) or, obviously, any 8-bit data. If those constraints are not completely comfortable, actually implementing QP might in fact be the easiest, least intrusive fix, because it relieves you from any constraints on the actual content.